# Is it possible to read unknown number of lines from console in C#?

Tags: c#, console

There is a function, which can read a single line from the console input (`Console.ReadLine()`), but I wish to read or some arbitrary number of lines, which is unknown at compile time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course it is. Just use just read a single line (using `ReadLine()` or whatever else you please) at a time within either a for loop (if you know at the beginning of reading how many lines you need) or within a while loop (if you want to stop reading when you reach `EOF` or a certain input).

**EDIT:**

Sure:

```
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
    // Do whatever you want here with line
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to do it with while loop, I do not know how to check if there is a next line or not! Some hints or an example, please!

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful, but how could I to determine which line is the last one? Currently the program will wait for a new line input.

Comment: I miss to comment about "(if you know at the beginning of reading how many lines you need)" - it is unknown, if there is no longer an input, that should mean end of it.

Comment: It will keep executing waiting for a line until it receives an indication that there are no more lines coming, which is the end of file signal, which is ctrl-Z on Windows I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the other answers here loop until a null line is encountered while others expect the user to type something special like "EXIT".  Keep in mind that reading from the console could be either a person typing or a redirected input file:

```
myprog.exe < somefile.txt
```

In the case of redirected input Console.ReadLine() would return null when it hits the end of the file.  In the case of a user running the program interactively they'd have to know to how to enter the end of file character (Ctrl+Z followed by enter or F6 followed by enter). If it is an interactive user you might need to let them know how to signal the end of input.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is use a loop:

```
string input;

Console.WriteLine("Input your text (type EXIT to terminate): ");
input = Console.ReadLine();

while (input.ToUpper() != "EXIT")
{
    // do something with input

    Console.WriteLine("Input your text(type EXIT to terminate): ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
string input;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input your text (type EXIT to terminate): ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input.ToUpper() != "EXIT")
    {
        // do something with the input
    }
} while (input.ToUpper() != "EXIT");
```

Answer (score 1):

simple example:

```
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
CountLinesInFile("test.txt"); // sample input in file format
}

static long CountLinesInFile(string f)
{
long count = 0;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
}
```