# Cannot read a list of strings separated by count of white spaces and few newline

Tags: c#, split

I want to read a *list of strings* separated by *multiple white spaces* and few lines. I'm trying to read this input:

```
@" 1427  0   

   876652098643267843 
5276538

   "
```

I use this:

```
List<string> input = Console
  .ReadLine()
  .Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine}, 
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .ToList();
```

With this command I receive list with **2** strings:
`1427` and `0`. The next ones *does not show up*.
Between `0` and the next one are some white spaces and a empty line.

Can't figure whether the problem is in reading from console or 
`.Split` function is not fully valid.

I simply want to:

```
input[0] = 1427;
input[1] = 0;
```

...
Thanks :)

Comment: try this -> Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { " ", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()

Comment: What do you expect from [Console.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline)? It read first line and ends. To read more lines you have to [use loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8707106/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

You can try *regular expressions* in order to `Match` all **Non**whitespace chunks:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = @" 1427 0

      876652098643267843 5276538

  ";

  List<input> input = Regex
    .Matches(source, @"\S+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, input
    .Select((v, i) => $"{nameof(input)}[{i}] = {v};")));
```

Output:

```
input[0] = 1427;
input[1] = 0;
input[2] = 876652098643267843;
input[3] = 5276538;
```

Another possibility is `Regex.Split`:

```
  List<string> input = Regex
    .Split(source, @"\s+")
    .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    .ToList();
```